# When using Blazor WebAssembly with Azure Function in "local mode" accessed via Http.GetStringAsync using IP I get an "Failed to fetch error"

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I'm working on a local dev config using:

- Azure Function via a local **func** emulator from visual studio
- Accessed via **Blazor WebAssembly** (via local IIS express).

The goal is to develop an WebAssembly App using Azure Function emulator in a local dev config, without having to publish each time on azure to make a test...

When I try to access a dummy function from the blazor app using `http.GetStringAsync()` method , I'm facing a problem when accessing the func emulator via the IP address, like these explanations :

1. when call from the blazor app using localhost like

   Http.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:7071/api/HelloEcho")   => localhost , it works, I got a response
2. when accessing the func api from a Chrome or Edge client using the localhost or IP adress, like typing this in browser or from a remote device :

   ```
   http://localhost:7071/api/HelloEcho    => it works 

   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7071/api/HelloEcho    => remote, it works
   ```

I even try taping it `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7071/api/HelloEcho` in a safari browser on my phone connected on the same network ==> it works , I get a response.

3. but when I'm trying to access it replacing the localhost by its IP **from the blazor app** like this
   `Http.GetStringAsync("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7071/api/HelloEcho")`    => i got an error message

> WebAssembly.JSException: TypeError: Failed to fetch at
> System.Net.Http.WebAssemblyHttpHandler.doFetch

If it works in a browser, why not using an `http.Get` in the app  ? and what can I do to make it working ?

---

NB : in the function host, added parameters for CORS : `*`

Visual studio Version 16.6.0 Preview 6.0

Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2534 Commit hash: bc1e9efa8fa78dd1a138dd1ac1ebef97aac8d78e)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.13353.0

WebAssembly 3.2.0-rc1.20223.4

Comment: Please use Chrome's network activity inspector (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network), to gather the error associated with the xhr request and append it to the question. The exact error will allow the community to get you pointed in the correct direction.

Comment: I checked in Chrome running the App

When : 
Http.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:7071/api/HelloEcho");   => OK, works


but when :
Http.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.x.x:7071/api/HelloEcho");   => error : Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:44349/functions' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://192.168.x.x:7071/api/HelloEcho'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_with_args @ dotnet.3.2.0-rc1.20222.2.js:1

Comment: precision : in the both case it's http://.... (h t tp://192.168.x.x:7071/api/HelloEcho   and   h t tp://localhost:7071/api/HelloEcho   )   - when localhost it works fine, when ip, error message...  (the http in my comment string here is removed by formatting :-)  )

Comment: Blazor WASM sucks. In simple words you can only call your own Web API (ex. Blazor Server), which is configured for this (CORS). You can't consume any 3rd party Web APIs from Blazor WebAssembly, which makes it unusable. I wasted few days to realize that.

Answer (score 0):

To test app you do not need IIS, you can run both function app and blazor app using ctrl + F5 and it will work well. 
I do so and had not any problems yet.
Do you really need IIS, why?

Comment: Hello. perhaps mismatching something, but when I say IIS **express**, it's the emulator in Visual studio ==>  I use the Ctrl+F5 in visual studio  (started as Admin, I already saw there was some problem when not started as admin). To be sure, I tested again Ctrl+F5, Got the same results. seing the details in the previous answer, I thing it's the http/https cross the origin of the problem. But not sure how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed content errors occur when your page is loaded over HTTPS, but your asynchronous requests attempt to communicate over HTTP. This is considered as a [security risk](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)

To resolve the issue, your can either "upgrade" both resources to HTTPS, or you can "downgrade" both to HTTP.

Rather than attempting to set up a certificate for an ip address, the use of a HOSTS file can allow you to create test dns entries, which allows you to avoid both ip addresses and port number entry altogether.